# How to configure monitorInterval in log4j.properties in log4j1.6

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j

I need to have a log4j configuration for `monitorInterval`. How can this be done with `log4j.properties`?

In `log4j.xml` it can be configured like this:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
```

What is the equivalent in `log4j.properties`?

Answer (score 1):

For `log4j2` you can use this `properties` file.

```
name = MainLogging

monitorInterval = 5

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = ERROR
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.additivity = false
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is configureAndWatch, see the symmetric question here:

[How to implement "configureAndWatch" in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843757/how-to-implement-configureandwatch-in-log4j2)