# How to implement "configureAndWatch" in log4j2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, log4j2

In `log4j`, there is a feature `configureAndWatch` (as mentioned below) where without application server restart, log threshold level can be modified with default delay.

```
org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4j.xml path);
```

Is this possible in `log4j2` as well ? If yes, then how can this be achieved ?

Also, below are lines of code for setting up and cleaning up `log4j` setup.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure()
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration()
```

How can this be achieved in `log4j2` ?  Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per Log4j2 documentation
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

> When configured from a File, Log4j has the ability to automatically detect changes to the configuration file and reconfigure itself. If the monitorInterval attribute is specified on the configuration element and is set to a non-zero value then the file will be checked the next time a log event is evaluated and/or logged and the monitorInterval has elapsed since the last check. The example below shows how to configure the attribute so that the configuration file will be checked for changes only after at least 30 seconds have elapsed. The minimum interval is 5 seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
...
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You have missed explanation to add log file path.